# Eigen error : INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT multiplying vector and matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

im working with c++ and eigen. I try to implement matrix rotation but i get this error `Eigen\src/Core/GeneralProduct.h(410,3): error C2338:  INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT`

```
    Eigen::Vector3f box_pos = Eigen::Vector3f(-2.0f, 2.5f, -2.0f);
    box_pos *= RotY(5.0f);
```

RotY function :

```
   Eigen::Matrix3f RotY(float angle) {
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    Eigen::Matrix3f matrix;
    matrix << c, 0., s, 0., 1., 0., -s, 0., c;
    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`box_pos` is a column vector. If you write `box_pos *= RotY(5.0f)` you multiply the matrix from the right side and the inner dimensions (1 and 3) do not match.

You either have to transpose `box_pos` and work with a row vector or rewrite the multiplication as

```
box_pos = RotY(5.0f) * box_pos;
```